# Preventing from Multiple primary key error

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc

This is my code for executing in my java program:

```
public static void createBooksTablesAndSetPK() {
    String selectDB = "Use lib8";
    String createBooksTable = "Create table IF NOT EXISTS books (ID int,Name varchar(20),ISBN varchar(10),Date date )";
    String bookTablePK = "ALTER TABLE BOOKS ADD PRIMARY KEY(id)";
    Statement st = null;
    try (
            Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection(dbUrl, "root", "2323");) {
        st = con.createStatement();
        st.execute(selectDB);
        st.execute(createBooksTable);
        st.execute(bookTablePK);

    } catch (SQLException sqle) {
        sqle.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

I cat use `IF NOT EXIST` for creating databasesand tables to prevent creating duplicate database and tables and corresponding errors.

But i don't know how prevent `Multiple primary key error`, because program may call `createBooksTablesAndSetPK()` multiple times.

Error:

```
com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: Multiple primary key defined
```

Comment: just move primary key definition to your "create table" statement

Comment: Or check if the table exists (I'm not sure if there's a SQL standard way of knowing this) before proceeding any further with your code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The column `Book_id` is not existing in your case. You are creating a table with ID as the column and then updating the table with a PRIMARY KEY constraint on a column that is not existing.

```
Create table IF NOT EXISTS books (ID int,Name varchar(20),ISBN varchar(10),Date date )

ALTER TABLE BOOKS ADD PRIMARY KEY(BOOK_id)
```

Try running these statements on a MySQL command prompt (or MySql Workbench) and the see the error.

You need change the alter table command like this.

```
ALTER TABLE BOOKS ADD BOOK_id VARCHAR( 255 ), ADD PRIMARY KEY(BOOK_id);
```